# How to follow ES6 way of receiving constants into test file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, cypress

Currently I am following ES5 way of receiving constants into my spec file. I would like to change that into ES6 style. could someone please suggest the best way to do that ?

// constants.js

```
 module.exports = Object.freeze({
      firstNameInput: "Cypress",
      lastNameInput: "Test",
      ms: 2000,
      tableId: 1,
      userEmail: "testingaccount@book.com",
      displayName: "Test Account",
    });
```

//   test.spec.js file

```
let constants = require("../../support/constants");

const tableId = constants.tableId;
const userEmail = constants.userEmail;
const displayName = constants.displayName;
```

Comment: If you only want to update the spec file you could put update the import to `import * as constants from "../../support/constants"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing more required than

```js
import constants from "../../support/constants"
```

Don't need to change the constants file, neither the way to refer to the variables.

No need to `import * as constants ...`, the above already does same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Update the `constants.js` file to use the export syntax instead of `module.exports`, like this:

```
export const firstNameInput = "Cypress";
export const lastNameInput = "Test";
...
```

Then in your `test.spec.js` file you could import the constants like this:

```
import { firstNameInput, lastNameInput, ... } from "../../support/constants";
```

Comment: Thanks Roniel, in my constants.j file i may have more than 30 items to export, so as per advised i need to repeat the below line several times for diff variables right ? is there a better way instead ? 
`export const lastNameInput = "Test";`

Comment: @soccerway If you have have a lot of constants **and you wanna use the es6 code style** you could use this: 

```const constants = { FOO: 'foo', BAR: 'bar', ... }; 
export { constants }; 
```

 And then you can use it like this: 

```import { constants } from './constants'; 
console.log(constants.FOO); 
```